# How to create a categorical variable in R with unequal categoris

Tags: r

I am trying to create categories of credit bureau scores. I have indiviudal scores for clients but I would like to create categories as follows: -1, 0, 1 - 50, 51 - 150, 151 - 250, 251+ I use R

Answer (score 1):

We can use `cut` or `findInterval`

```
cut(Scores, breaks = c(-Inf, -1, 1, 51, 151, 251, Inf))
```